# Checking if email is verified in aws cognito using AWS Amplify Authentication module

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using the JavaScript AWS Amplify Authentication module. If an existing and confirmed user changes their email address, the user in the cognito user pool is set to **not verified** and the user is sent a verification code to the new email address.  However, I can't find any way with the API to determine if the current user's email is verified or not verified.  How can I find out if the user's email address is verified or not via the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out...  so for anyone else trying to figure this out:

You need to set the read permissions on the App client to read the Email Verified attribute.

Go to: General settings -> App clients -> Show details -> Set attribute read and write permissions link and check off Readable Attributes: Email Verified

Comment: I did find the option in cognito, but still email_verified does not appear in my user attributes. What other settings are you aware of that would be necessary?

Comment: Uh, ok found answer here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2827 So apparently new attributes won't load until accessToken is renewed.